# Manipulating Big Data with Little RAM

Tags: r, ram, data-manipulation, large-data, bigdata

I am currently working with data that has 70 million rows and 5 columns and I have little RAM to work with so I am using the `ff` package to perform my operations. Here is the first 20 rows of my data:

```
      date     ZCTA   Precip_flag x_1234  splitBy
1   01/01/2010 1001           1    100 01/01/2010_100
2   01/01/2010 1002           1    100 01/01/2010_100
3   01/01/2010 1003           1    100 01/01/2010_100
4   01/01/2010 1005           1    100 01/01/2010_100
5   01/01/2010 1007           1    100 01/01/2010_100
6   01/01/2010 1008           1    100 01/01/2010_100
7   01/01/2010 1009           1    100 01/01/2010_100
8   01/01/2010 1010           1    101 01/01/2010_101
9   01/01/2010 1011           1    101 01/01/2010_101
10  01/01/2010 1012           1    101 01/01/2010_101
11  01/01/2010 1013           1    101 01/01/2010_101
12  01/01/2010 1020           1    102 01/01/2010_102
13  01/01/2010 1022           1    102 01/01/2010_102
14  01/01/2010 1026           1    102 01/01/2010_102
15  01/01/2010 1027           1    102 01/01/2010_102
16  01/01/2010 1028           1    102 01/01/2010_102
17  01/01/2010 1029           1    102 01/01/2010_102
18  01/01/2010 1030           1    103 01/01/2010_103
19  01/01/2010 1031           1    103 01/01/2010_103
20  01/01/2010 1032           1    103 01/01/2010_103
```

I would like to sum the `Precip_flag` column by `date` and `x_1234`, however I am having trouble with how big the data is and continue to get the error: `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 272.9 Mb`

If I perform the following operation on a small set of the data like that above (20 rows), my result comes perfectly:

```
Rollup_subset1 <- ffdfdply(subset1, split = (subset1$splitBy), 
 FUN=function(x){summaryBy(Precip_flag ~ date + x_1234, data=x,
                 FUN=sum, keep.names=FALSE) }, 
 trace=TRUE)

Rollup_subset1

       date   x_1234 Precip_flag.sum
  1 01/01/2010  100        7         
  2 01/01/2010  101        4         
  3 01/01/2010  102        6         
  4 01/01/2010  103        3
```

How can I perform this task, but on the 70 million rows without running out of RAM?

Comment: You can perform on several subsets, then union the results and perform once more

Comment: I haven't used ff, but I guess you could save space by storing dates as dates or integer dates (offered by, e.g., the data.table package) rather than using strings; and by storing flags as boolean/logical. Of course, you could do without `splitBy` entirely. `object.size(1:7e7)` suggests that one column of your data should be ~280 MB if stored as integer or bool, so if you have 4 GB or more, you could maybe do your work in RAM.

Comment: It is maybe a simple question but what size did you put for the next.row parameter when creating the ff objects?

Comment: I don't recall setting the size. Do you know what option would allow for this? Thanks.